# How to prevent the highlighting of InlineUIContainer on mouse click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, flowdocument

Consider the following `FlowDocument` inside a WPF `RichTextBox`:

```xml
<RichTextBox Width="150" FontSize="30">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run Text="abc"/>
      <InlineUIContainer>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Width="30" Height="20"/>
      </InlineUIContainer>
      <Run Text="def"/>
    </Paragraph>
  </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

When I click on the `Border` it becomes highlighted in blue:

[image: highlight]

How can I prevent that? I would like it to position the caret instead, like this:

[image]

I have already tried the following properties without success:

- `IsHitTestVisible = false`
- `IsEnabled = false`
- `IsManipulationEnabled = false`
- `Focusable = false`
- `IsFocused = false`

Comment: It is possible to use the `RichTextBox.SelectionChanged` event and if a selection contains the `InlineUIContainer` then cancel the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this xaml:

```
 <RichTextBox x:Name="rchText" Width="150" FontSize="30">
      <FlowDocument MouseDown="rch_MouseDown">
         <Paragraph>
              <Run Text="abc"/>
              <InlineUIContainer>
             <Border x:Name="brdText" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Width="30" Height="20"/>
             </InlineUIContainer>
             <Run Text="def"/>
        </Paragraph>
     </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

then:

```
private void rch_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(rchText);
   var borderPos = brdText.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), rchText);
   if(mousePoint.X > borderPos.X && mousePoint.X < (borderPos.X + brdText.ActualWidth) && mousePoint.Y > borderPos.Y && mousePoint.Y < (borderPos.Y + brdText.ActualWidth))
   {
     e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a very good suggestion, extremely helpful. FYI I also ended up using `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest()` in order to know what object was actually clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `RichTextBox.SelectionChanged` event to cancel the selection
of an `InlineUIContainer`:

```
private void Rtb_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        rtb.SelectionChanged -= Rtb_SelectionChanged;
        InlineUIContainer inline = null;
        var curr = rtb.CaretPosition.Parent;
        if (curr is Run run)
        {
            if (run.NextInline is InlineUIContainer nuic)
            {
                inline = nuic;                        
            }
            else if (run.PreviousInline is InlineUIContainer puic)
            {
                inline = puic;                        
            }

            if (inline != null && rtb.Selection.Contains(inline.ContentStart) 
                && rtb.Selection.Contains(inline.ContentEnd))
            {
                var current = rtb.CaretPosition;
                rtb.Selection.Select(current, current);
            }
        }
        rtb.SelectionChanged += Rtb_SelectionChanged;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish I could accept two answers, because in order to achieve exactly what I needed, I ended up overriding both `OnSelectionChanged` and `OnMouseDown`, as the other answer suggested.